# Minimal polynomial and diagonalizable matrix: property

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Quick question

We know that if a matrix/linear transformation in a space has dimension n and its minimal polynomial has k different roots with algebraic multiplicity 1, that the matrix/linear transformation is diagonalizable.

Now can k be different than n? Or do we need to have n different roots for the minimal polynomial (I know it's sufficient (but not necessary) n different roots in the characteristic polynomial but I read that that's not needed for the minimal polynomial I just want to confirm)

Comment: What's the minimal polynomial of a space? What does it mean to diagonalize a space?

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about what I wrote. Diagonalize a linear transformation or a matriz is what I meant. And also it's the minimal polynomial of the matrix/linear transformation. My apologies.

Comment: Can you help me @GerryMyerson?

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix having dimension $n$? "Dimension" is a property of vector spaces, not a property of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $k$ can very well be different than $n$. For example, if $A = I_n$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)$ while the characteristic polynomial is $(x - 1)^n$.